# .NET Membership for 2 domains

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership

I have an existing website with .NET membership configured against the same SQL database that the website uses for the rest of it's data.

I recently have created a new website, on a new domain, that shares data by using the same database (SQL Server 2008).

I have configured ,NET Membership n the first website/domain, and it works fine, with registration, login and password reset/change working fine.

I would like to use the same membership database on my new site. I have added the System.Web.Security namespace, and linked the Membership_ConnectionString to the same SQL database, but the login that works on my first domain does not work on my second domain/website, even when running on localhost, from VisualStudio 2010.

I require existing users of my existing website to NOT have to register to Login to my new website/domain.

Any ideas?